# Powershell 2.0 Ping list of computers and send email on failure

Tags: arrays, email, loops, powershell

I am new at PowerShell and I have been researching this issue, but I have not been able to find what I am looking for yet.  The site is still using PowerShell 2, and it cannot be upgraded.

I have a list of servers that I want to ping to verify that they are up, and I am using a text file to populate the names.  I have the pinging part of the script working and the emailing part working just fine.  Now I am trying to combine the two to email about a specific server that fails.

I am using the following:

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName (Get-Content Computers.txt) -Delay 5 -Quiet
```

This returns the boolean values of true or false for each computer.

I know that the `Get-Content` automatically creates an array. So is the best way to get the results written as an associative array, or is there a way to get the `Test-Connection` to loop one at a time through the Computers.txt array and then just send the email on a failure when it is on that specific server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Content Computers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Delay 5 -Quiet) {
        #Send email that it was a success
    } else {
        #Computer unreachable
    }
}
```

Basically you pipe the list of computers to a foreach-object loop, and iterate through the list, pinging each computer and sending the email.